# How to remove background?

Tags: camera

I wish to remove the background of these videos: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=117AB4E465BB25B0!25610&authkey=!AFwzaPNg8TirZQ8

However, sometimes the camera moves up and other things can be seen. How can I remove that too?

Comment: Have you tried masking it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use masks to isolate your objects from the background. These masks can be animated with keyframes or attached to a tracker to stay on the objects. But it is quite cumbersome.

Masking tutorial: http://learningblender3dsoftware.blogspot.de/2012/10/blender-264-tutorial-intro-to-masking.html

Video tutorial which covers masks in combination with Trackers: http://www.blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/424-tutorial-sin-city-effect-in-blender.html (click the third link below the video: "8:50 - 12:40 ...")

Blender wiki: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Mask_Editor

Comment: would making a green screen be easier? Thanks :)

Comment: That depends. To be effective a green screen has to be lit evenly. And ideally have a distance to the foreground objects. Otherwise you have a lot of green reflections on the foreground. It is always work to isolate objects :)