# How to make objects in a video glow?

Tags: video

Regarding my [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3708/how-to-remove-background), how to remove background, I wish to do the following:
There will be a narration so I will need each object to glow while I talk about them, how can you do this? Please demonstrate on one (or more) of the videos.

Thanks in advance

EDIT

I would like the object to emit light, affecting the other objects.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "glow"? Do you want these objects to appear brighter or should they emit light that affects the environment or do you want something like a fuzzy glowing outline? A single still image would help.

Comment: Please add some more details to the question, it is not exactly clear what you are asking. Try not to reference other posts too much when asking and instead try to create a unique, self-contained question.

Comment: You might be interested in this ideo tutorial: http://www.blendernerd.com/five-ways-to-create-glow/

Comment: @iKlsR I know but gandalf3 told me not to put two question in one question so I had no choice but to do this.

Comment: @Fweeb look at the edited question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for a tutorial. Instead of giving you the tutorial (this is not a place to demonstrate a whole tutorial) I am going to show you a workflow. Now you can google each of these topics.

- Import movie into blender.
- Render out as separate images (for convenience).
- Place a grey plane in front of the camera.
- Shine a spotlight on it where the object you want to glow is.
- Insert keyframes and move the light. The light will get animated. Seeing the images from the video in the background helps.
- Use the compositor in blender to render out a new movie. The grey plane should be multiplied with the images you rendered out earlier.